# UICollectionViewCell unselected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

When I select cell, is selected, and when I select another cell is selected and unselected previous cell, OK

So I want when I click on selected cell I want to unselected same cell

I use this code

```
override var selected: Bool {
       get {
            return super.selected
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                super.selected = true
                self.shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "EEEEEE")
            } else if newValue == false {
                super.selected = false
                self.shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this widget behaves like a radio button, once one is selected you cannot deselect all buttons of the same group with standard behavior.

So, you have to listen Taps events on the `UICollectionViewCell` cells and when the user taps an already selected cell, deselect it.